# Creating an array with char in C, taking two words from the user, changing the places of the words and giving them all to the screen at the end

Tags: arrays, c, string, printf, scanf

Expected result:

### input:

4

Anya Taylor

Bill Camp

Dennis Lewis

Moses Ingram

### output:

Taylor Anya

Camp Bill

Lewis Dennis

Ingram Moses

I've tried so many things.
Although there are those who have encountered similar problems on the internet, I have not come across such an example.

Note: I'm looking for a solution except for special libraries and array functions that make it easy.
I thought something like while (array [i]! = '\ 0'). I wanted to create a new array, save it there and print it out. But I failed what I thought.

```
#include<stdio.h>   
int main(void)    
{
    int nbnames=0,i=0;
char Fname[101];
char Lname[101];
scanf("%d",&nbnames);
for(i=0;i<nbnames;i++)
{
    scanf("%s %s",Fname,Lname);
    printf("%s %s\n",Lname,Fname);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Huh?   Not sure I understand how you get from the input example to the output.

Comment: First we get the number of people to register.
we add records (name, surname)
then we print the records on the screen (surname, name)

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty trivial. For convenience, you can use a `struct` to store the first name and last name of each person-

```c
typedef struct Person
{
    char first_name[101];
    char last_name[101];
} Person;
```

Now, all you have to do, is just allocate an array of `Person` structs, of size `nbnames` (given by user) - and then simply scan in the first name and last name as you already are and store them in each `Person` struct of the array.

So the full program would look like-

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person
{
    char first_name[101];
    char last_name[101];
} Person;

int main(void)
{
    Person* persons = NULL;
    size_t nbnames;
    /* Get the number of persons to be entered */
    if (scanf("%u", &nbnames) != 1)
    {
        /* scanf could not parse input - probably not an unsigned integer */
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* Allocate enough memory for the array of persons */
    persons = malloc(nbnames * sizeof(*persons));
    if (!persons)
    {
        /* Failed allocating memory */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory for persons array\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* Take the inputs */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbnames; i++)
    {
        scanf("%100s %100s", persons[i].first_name, persons[i].last_name);
    }
    /* Print the outputs */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbnames; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n", persons[i].last_name, persons[i].first_name);
    }
    /* Free the persons array */
    free(persons);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

> 4
>
> Anya Taylor
>
> Bill Camp
>
> Dennis Lewis
>
> Moses Ingram
>
> Taylor Anya
>
> Camp Bill
>
> Lewis Dennis
>
> Ingram Moses